# Select distinct values from table and put them in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
SELECT
    g.[Id],
    --br.name
    --por.id
  FROM [Game] AS g
  INNER JOIN [GameAvailability] AS ga ON ga.[GameId] = g.[Id]
  INNER JOIN [Portal] AS por ON por.Id = ga.PortalId
  INNER JOIN [Brand] AS br ON br.Id = por.BrandId
```

What I want to accomplish is to put all available brand names from [Brand] table connected to some Game in one string and select those values in the select clause.

Each gameid can be connected to more than one portal and brand.

For example, my final result would be as shown below:

```
GameId        BrandNameList
1             'test1, test2'
2             'test3,test 4'
```

Comment: Can you provide the each table schema and sample data in the form of SQL Script so it will be easy to verify the solution by editing your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.Id,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + g1.[name]
         FROM 
         (
           SELECT g.[Id],
           br.name,
           FROM [Game] AS g
           INNER JOIN [GameAvailability] AS ga ON ga.[GameId] = g.[Id]
           INNER JOIN [Portal] AS por ON por.Id = ga.PortalId
           INNER JOIN [Brand] AS br ON br.Id = por.BrandId
         )
         g1
         WHERE g.Id = g1.Id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'') BrandNameList
FROM 
(
           SELECT g.[Id],
           br.name,
           FROM [Game] AS g
           INNER JOIN [GameAvailability] AS ga ON ga.[GameId] = g.[Id]
           INNER JOIN [Portal] AS por ON por.Id = ga.PortalId
           INNER JOIN [Brand] AS br ON br.Id = por.BrandId
)g;
```

Comment: I have data mismatch. Probably INNER JOIN [GameAvailability] AS ga ON ga.[GameId] = g.[Id]. I got doubled results when i join this table, but with distinct i lost some data from Game table. I must have all records from Game table and as a last column in the select string of brands

Comment: @user2171512 It will be better if you provide the sample data as said in the comment. Till now try with the left join hope it can work.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT g.[Id], STRING_AGG(br.name, ',')
FROM [Game] g JOIN
     [GameAvailability] ga
     ON ga.[GameId] = g.[Id] JOIN
     [Portal] por
     ON por.Id = ga.PortalId JOIN
     [Brand] br
     ON br.Id = por.BrandId
GROUP BY g.Id;
```

Comment: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @user2171512 what version of SQL Server are you using? Since I use an older version of SQL Server, I need to use `FOR XML` to concatenate rows.

Comment: Ver: 12.0.6372.1 (SQL SERVER 2014). I need this to run also on this and newer versions. I tried to 2016 and returns a result but on 2014 it returns error